# Fixed number of results per page

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I limit the number of results that populate in the `Details` section to a fixed number per page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, configure the Details section to force a page break every ten records.

1. Put a suppressed running total called `RecordCount` in the Details section. Make it increment every time a record is printed.
2. Create a formula called `CountPerPage` and set its value to `10`. (Or make it a parameter if you want the user to be able to choose how many records per page.)
3. Set the Detail's *New Page After* to `(#RecordCount} Mod {@CountPerPage} = 0`

Comment: Just to get the steps straight: If I right click `Details' go to `Section Expert` I should `Suppress` and add a formula there? What's the exact formula? Thanks

Comment: @kazzi Not quite: You'll want to make a Running Total that counts the number of records. Place it inside your Details section, and it will show 1, 2, 3, 4... on each line. Suppress the Running Total, and you can use it in formulas without having to see the number on each line.

Comment: I did the suppressed running total, and created a formula and put its value to 10. However, wasn't sure where to place the Detail's New Page After. However, after going to the Section Expert for Details, under Paging, I saw "New Page After" and set 10 on Visible Records, and that seemed to work